# Start/Stop SVG Animation

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'd like to use this beautiful SVG animation posted on CodePen, but I can't figure out how to start or restart the animation:

https://codepen.io/elevaunt/pen/JYRBzJ

***the HTML***

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <polyline class="path check" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>
</svg>
<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <line class="path line" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="34.4" y1="37.9" x2="95.8" y2="92.3"/>
  <line class="path line" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="95.8" y1="38" x2="34.4" y2="92.2"/>
</svg>
<p class="error">Bummer!</p>
```

***the CSS***

```
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  &.circle {
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
    animation: dash .9s ease-in-out;
  }
  &.line {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    -webkit-animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
  &.check {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
    -webkit-animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation: dash-check .9s .35s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  &.success {
    color: #73AF55;
  }
  &.error {
    color: #D06079;
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}

@keyframes dash-check {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
  }
}
```

**Q:** *Might anyone have any idea how I could hide the animation then show and activate it at the click of a button?*

Any help is much appreciated. TIA!

Comment: I would do this kind of animations using transitions and checkboxes

Comment: @enxaneta Could you provide some working example?

Comment: I've added 2 working examples. Please take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my answer. 
The example in Codepen is using `stroke-dasharray:1000`. This can give you problems. The stroke-dasharray value has to be equal to the length of the path.  I've recalculated the length of the paths, however I keep the same timing. You may want to change the timing to something else.

Also: the checkboxes are visible, but in practice you hide those checkboxes.

I've added a border to the svg element to be clear where you have to click. In practice I would use another path maybe light grey underneath the animated path.

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}


.path.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 390.2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 390.2px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .9s ease-in-out;
  
}
.path.line {
  stroke-dasharray: 82.033px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 82.033px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
.path.check {
  stroke-dasharray: 99.21px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 99.21px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
p.success {
  color: #73af55;
}
p.error {
  color: #d06079;
}


svg{border:1px solid}

#a:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#a:checked + svg  .path.check{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}


#b:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#b:checked + svg  .path.line{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="a" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <polyline  class="path check" fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>
  </svg></label>

<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>



<label><input id="b" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <circle class="path circle" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
  <line class="path line" id="kk" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="34.4" y1="37.9" x2="95.8" y2="92.3"/>
  <line class="path line" fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="95.8" y1="38" x2="34.4" y2="92.2"/>
</svg></label>
```

As I've commented before in practice I would use another path maybe light grey underneath the animated path. For this I save the paths in a `<defs>` element and I'm using those elements with `<use>`

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}


.path.circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 390.2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 390.2px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .9s ease-in-out;
  
}
.path.line {
  stroke-dasharray: 82.033px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 82.033px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
.path.check {
  stroke-dasharray: 99.21px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 99.21px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset .35s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .9s;
  
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0 60px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
p.success {
  color: #73af55;
}
p.error {
  color: #d06079;
}

.base{fill:none;stroke:#d9d9d9;stroke-width:6;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-linecap:round;}


#a:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#a:checked + svg  .path.check{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}


#b:checked + svg  .path.circle{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
#b:checked + svg  .path.line{stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="a" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <defs>
   <circle id="c"  cx="65.1" cy="65.1" r="62.1"/>
   <polyline id="py" fill="none" points="100.2,40.2 51.5,88.8 29.8,67.5 "/>    
  </defs>
  <g  class="base">
  <use xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use xlink:href="#py"/>
  </g>
  <g fill="none" stroke="#73AF55" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10">
  <use class="path circle" xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use class="path check" xlink:href="#py"/>
  </g>
  </svg></label>

<p class="success">Oh Yeah!</p>



<label><input id="b" type="checkbox" />
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 130.2 130.2">
  <defs>
  <line id="l1" x1="34.4" y1="37.9" x2="95.8" y2="92.3"/>
  <line id="l2" x1="95.8" y1="38" x2="34.4" y2="92.2"/>
  </defs>
  
  <g class="base">
  <use xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use xlink:href="#l1"/>
  <use xlink:href="#l2"/>
  </g>
  
  
  <g fill="none" stroke="#D06079" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round">
  <use class="path circle" xlink:href="#c"/>
  <use class="path line" xlink:href="#l1"/>
  <use class="path line" xlink:href="#l2"/>
  </g>
</svg></label>
  

<p class="error">Bummer!</p>
```

Comment: That's simply brilliant! Thank you so kindly. Would there be any issues reversing the tick mark, to move from _down to up_ rather than _up to down_ ? I've changed the **stroke-dashoffset** to  -99.21px and it seems to work.

Comment: If this is working is perfect. An other solution would be reversing the polyline like so: `<polyline id="py" fill="none" points="29.8,67.5 51.5,88.8 100.2,40.2"/>`

Comment: Thanks again! That might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Found some functions to pause unpause SVG animations. They pause an entire SVG element, to access them you must provide an ID attribute to the SVG.

unpauseAnimations()
pauseAnimations()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement
https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#__svg__SVGSVGElement__pauseAnimations

```js
function startBlur() {
    var cosa = document.getElementById("cosa");
    cosa.unpauseAnimations();//to start SVG animations
}

function stopBlur() {
    var cosa = document.getElementById("cosa");
    cosa.pauseAnimations(); //to pause SVG animations
}
```

```html
<svg height="110" width="110" id="cosa">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" edgeMode = "duplicate">
      <animate id="pp" attributeName="stdDeviation"
                  begin="0s" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                  values="0;15;0;"/>
</feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
<svg height="110" width="110">
  <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
<span onclick="startBlur()">START BLUR</span>
<span onclick="stopBlur()">PAUSE BLUR</span>
```